# How to create Azure Function App Service in isolated process

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I tried to create Azure Function App Service from Azure Portal, but I can't choose isolated process when I create it, and the configuration from portal FUNCTION_WORKER_RUNTIME is always default to be "dotnet".

[image]

if I manually change it to be "dotnet-isolated"

[image]

Then there is an error as below, and the function app doesn't working.

[image]

How can I create an isolated process function app service?

Answer (score 1):

> How to create Azure Function App Service in isolated process

One of the ways creating is by doing below process:

Firstly, I created a Dotnet 6 Isolated Framework in Local Environment(Visual Studio) :

```
   <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

[image]

Then code it and Publish it to Azure Function In Portal.

I get `Dotnet-Isolated` as below:

[image]

So I would suggest you to create locally Dot-Net Isolated Function and then Publish it to Azure.

And your warning says that Dotnet Isolated coding or editing cannot be done in Portal, it can only be done in local and then be published to azure.